# Items in array A but not in set B

Tags: python, arrays, boolean, difference

I have the below set of features:

```
|            | Sweet | Sour  | Bitter | Salty | Seeds |


| Grapefruit |    1     |    1     |    1      |    0     |    1     |

| Banana     |    1     |    0     |    0      |    0     |    0     |


grapefruit_features = np.array([True,  True,  True,  False, True ])
banana_features     = np.array([True,  False, False, False, False])
```

given two Boolean arrays (a and b), I need to write a function that tells me the number of features a has that b does not. So the features that a grapefruit has that a banana does not. (grapefruit - banana). it should return 3. {in the case (banana - grapefruit) should return 0 because banana has no features that grapfruit does not}

I just have the following code which on describes which features are not equal and I need help to fix it.

```
def differences(a, b):
   return np.sum(np.all([a != b] ,axis=0))
```

Comment: Your example code is for counting when a is not equal to b, but you want to count when a is true and b is not. How would you make that change?

Comment: You want to convert a and not b into a boolean expression

Answer (score 3):

AND `a` with the negation of `b` and find the sum, that's exactly the boolean logic equivalent of what you're looking for.

```
def differences(a, b):
    return (a & ~b).sum()
```

```
In [80]: differences(grapefruit_features, banana_features)
Out[80]: 3

In [81]: differences(banana_features, grapefruit_features)
Out[81]: 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!